# In Python how do I search for and count/print a specific set of characters in each item/string in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to eventually display all the items in my list that have the file ending .shp. So I need to be able to index each list item separately. Any suggestions?

This is what I have so far:

```
folderPath = r'K:\geog 173\LabData'

import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = (folderPath)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fileList = os.listdir(folderPath)
print fileList


"""Section 2: Identify and Print the number
and names of all shapefiles in the file list:"""

numberShp = 0

shpList= list()

for fileName in fileList:
    print fileName

fileType = fileName[-4:]
print fileType

if fileType == '.shp':
    numberShp +=1
    shpList.append(fileName)

print shpList
print numberShp
```

Comment: Two points of style... 1) It is more idiomatic to use `shpList = []` than `shpList = list()` in python, and 2) you should define `shpList` closer to the code where you use it so that it is easier to follow when you look at it 3 months from now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quite easily with [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
shpList = [fileName for fileName in fileList if fileName.endswith('.shp')]

print shpList
print len(shpList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You Please specify the desired output format. That would make the job easy...

One Probable Answer would be

```
fileList = [f for f in os.listdir('K:\geog 173\LabData') if f.endswith('.shp')]

for i,val in enumerate(fileList):
    print '%d. %s' %(i,val)  

#If u want to print the length of the list again...
print len(fileList)
```